# What are the terminals of a 6 wired step down transformer?

Tags: transformer

I'm having a Transformer with 2 input wires and 6 output wires(in pair).I dont know it ratings also.Please help me to find what the terminals are?

Comment: The terminals are wires connecting to bits of the coil inside. There's a myriad of ways it could be connected up - is it 3 individual coils, 2 centre tap coils? One coil with 6 taps? A 4 tap coil and a 2 tap coil?  Your guess is as good as ours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like this transformer has a total of 4 windings.  How do you know one of them is intended to be the input and the others output?

Physical size will give you some idea of what power this transformer is intended to handle.  Since you gave no indication of that, there is little more I can say about it.

The first thing to do is to probe the wires with a ohmmeter.  At the very least, verify that you really do have 4 independent windings.  That means you should have some finite resistance between each wire pair, but infinite resistance between pairs.  If this is not the case, then you have multiple taps from fewer windings.

To find the winding ratio, put a small sine wave into one of the windings.  Use the "input" winding if you're pretty sure that's how the transformer is intended to be used.  A few 100 Hz to 1 kHz at a few volts should be fine.  Measure the voltage the winding is actually being driven with after it loads the signal generator.  Now measure the open circuit voltage of all the other windings.  The ratio of these to the voltage on the input winding is the turns ratio.  This open circuit voltage relationship will scale up to larger voltages.

Comment: Always Olin!!!! BIG FAN!

Comment: Sir,Thanks for your answer.The transformer has 3 pairs of output wires with 3 different colours.When I measure resistance between different colured wires I get Infinite resistance(i.e. 1).But when I measure between same coloured wires it shows 0 resistance(you said finite resistance but i dont get it).

Comment: Sir I want to know the voltage rating of my transformer.Can I connect the 2 wires in the input side to 220V AC and measure the output voltage between each pair of windings using a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Something to add to Olin's answer: if this is a power transformer intended to be operated from the AC Mains, you can check to see if it's actually possible to do so by connecting what you think the primary (input) winding is to the AC mains through a smallish incandescent light bulb.  This will allow you to determine if the core is saturating at that voltage.

Normally, a power transformer connected to AC Mains supply through a light bulb *and* with no load (nothing connected to the output leads) will cause the light bulb to be completely dark or just barely glowing.  If the bulb glows brightly, the input voltage is too high and the core is saturating.

I use a 60 Watt bulb for my testing.